# Why does Jersey 2.22 have "javax.servlet-api-3.0.1" included in the Jersey bundle?

Tags: java, servlets, jersey

Servlet Spec 3.0:

> Web Application Class Loader
>   The class loader that a container uses to load a servlet in a WAR must allow the
>   developer to load any resources contained in library JARs within the WAR following
>   normal Java SE semantics using getResource. As described in the Java EE license
>   agreement, servlet containers that are not part of a Java EE product should not allow
>   the application to override Java SE platform classes, such as those in the java.* and
>   javax.* namespaces, that Java SE does not allow to be modified. The container 
>   should not allow applications to override or access the container’s implementation
>   classes

So given that, I don't understand why Jersey 2.22 has the javax.servlet-api-3.0.1 jar included in the Jersey 2.22 bundle. Is there any rational explanation why it's there? By default, I believe that containers such as Glassfish, Tomcat, etc, have their own servlet-api.jar in the lib directory.

Comment: Odd they they would add a `provided` jar. It sure isn't pulled in when we use Maven. My guess is that it's because Jersey supports the injection of Servlet components, `HttpServletRequest/Response`, `ServletContext`. That's just a guess. But even including the jar into your project, you should make sure it is not built into the final war. You should always use the server provided one.

Comment: That's what I thought as well... weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check this [link](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.22.1/jersey/project/jersey-container-servlet/dependencies.html), you'll realize it's a *provided dependency*, which means that the dependency is *required to compile the application*, but should be *provided by default when using the library*.

The [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) explains how the `provided` dependency scope works:

> This is much like `compile` [dependency scope], but indicates you
>   expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime.
>   For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise
>   Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related
>   Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides
>   those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and
>   test classpath, and is not transitive.

The [Jersey 2.22.x bundle](https://jersey.java.net/download.html) contains the JAX-RS 2.0 API jar, all the core Jersey module jars as well as all the required 3rd-party dependencies.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, the javax.servlet-api.jar is required for Jersey just for compile time. For runtime, it will be using whatever .jar is in the classpath of my servlet containers (Tomcat - servlet-api.jar). Is that correct?

Comment: @MiguelPortugal Exactly! In the case of Jersey 2.22.x, your server must provide the javax.servlet-api dependency.

Comment: Alright! Weird thing is that I didn't include javax.servlet-api.jar on my build path but my application compiled and worked just fine. It it probably because I wasn't using anything from that .jar?

Comment: @MiguelPortugal If your application doesn't use the javax.servlet-api.jar directly, it should compile fine. If you try compiling Jersey 2.22.x source without that JAR, it'll fail.